# Why does this react form works only for the first time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a Search Form component which on Submit will pass the input value to the component. The issue is when the searched component is reused by the the redirected Component from submitting the form I receive an error of undefined.

Here is the Search Form Component

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const SearchForm = ()=>{
const [text,setText] = useState('');
const history = useHistory();

const handleChange = (e)=>{
 setText(e.target.value)
}

const handleSubmit = (e)=>{    
 history.push({
   pathname: '/search',
   state: {
     search: text
   }
 })
 setText('');
}


return (
   <div className="searchForm">
         <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
           <input type="text" onChange = {handleChange} value = {text}/>
           <button type = "submit" className = "banner banner-button btn-sm">Search</button>
         </form>
       </div>
)
}

export default SearchForm

Here is the Component to which renders on submitting the form and passing the searched value


import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'
import Navbar from '../../Navbar/Navbar'
import SearchForm from '../../SearchForm/SearchForm'

import Loading from '../../Loading/Loading'
import SearchResult from './SearchResult'


import './search.css'
const Search = () => {
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
const [movies,setMovies] = useState([]);
const location =useLocation();
const searchedTerm = location.state;
useEffect(()=>{
 setLoading(true);
 const get = async(term)=>{
   const res = await fetch(`/${term}`)
   const data = await res.json();
   return data;
 }
 get(searchedTerm.search)
 .then((response)=>{
   setMovies(response.data.movies)
   setLoading(false);
 })
 .catch((err)=> console.log(err));
},[])


return (
 <div className = 'searched-video'>
   <Navbar/>
   {/* <SearchForm /> */}
   {loading ? <Loading/> : 
     <div className="searched-content">
       {   
           movies.map((element,index)=>{
           return (<SearchResult key = {index}  title = {element.title_english} runtime = {element.runtime} genres = {element.genres[0]} summary = {element.summary} img = {element.medium_cover_image} hash = {element.torrents[0].hash} quality = {element.torrents[0].quality} />)
         })
       }
   </div>
   }
 </div>
)
}

export default Search
```

It would be really helpful if anyone helps this issue. Thanks!

Comment: `"I receive an error of undefined"` What specifically is `undefined`? Please post the entire error

Comment: @Samathingamajig **TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined** . i edited the question and inserted the component to which the data is passed. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The submit handler doesn't prevent the default form action when submitting the form, the page and app are reloading and you lose the route state for the transition.

## Solution

Prevent the default form action. You probably don't need to also clear `text` state since the route transition likely unmounts this component anyway.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();    // <-- prevent form submission reloading page
  history.push({
    pathname: '/search',
    state: {
      search: text
    }
  });
}
```